# MSMQ requires AD certificate, but we are using a service account

Tags: active-directory, certificate, msmq, msmq-wcf

**Issue:**
How do you create the AD certificates MSMQ requires of an AD account, which are auto-created per computer in AD upon first login, without actually logging on as said account?

**Background:**

We are using WCF + MSMQ for a project.  The "MSMQ client" is actually a zero-interaction windows service, processing data and sending it to the queue.  In our production (and thus test/etc) environments, this windows service runs as a service account.

- This service account IS in AD
- This service account does NOT have permission to log in interactively, and WILL NEVER be given that permission
- Setting security to "off" as per [wcf msmq service activation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148409/wcf-msmq-service-activation-fails/1149824#1149824) is not an option, as this is a secure environment

Answer (score 1):

Here are some blog posts with some ideas in that may help or inform:

- [How to send authenticated MSMQ
  messages without using a domain
  account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/01/23/how-to-send-authenticated-msmq-messages-without-using-a-domain-account.aspx)
- [Clearing up MSMQ
  certificates from Active
  Directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/09/15/clearing-up-msmq-certificates-from-active-directory.aspx)

Cheers
John Breakwell